# SQL Server 2008 CLR vs T-SQL: Is there an efficiency/speed difference?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, clr, sqlclr

I'm a C# developer who has done some basic database work in T-SQL. However, I need to write a very complicated stored procedure, well above my T-SQL knowledge.

Will writing a stored procedure in C# using the .net CLR as part of SQL Server 2008 cause my stored procedure to be less efficient than if it were written in T-SQL? Is the difference (if any) significant? Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`CLR` require some communication overhead (to pass data between the `CLR` and `SQL Server`)

Rule of thumb is:

- If your logic mostly includes transformations of massive sets of data, which can be performed using set operations, then use `TSQL`.
- If your logic mostly includes complex computations of relatively small amounts of data, use `CLR`.

With set operations much more can be done than it seems. If you post your requirements here, probably we'll be able to help.

Comment: How big of a communication overhead are we talking about? I do have massive sets of data, but I also am doing complex computations on it rather than set operations.

Comment: `@bytenik`: this heavily depends on what you are going to do with the data. A built-in `SQL` aggregate function, for instance, works about `3` times as fast as a `CLR` aggregate. If you are going, say, to join two recordsets, you'll need to develop and hardcode the join into the `CLR`, while `SQL Server` has several native algorithms and selects the most appropriate one, which may increase performance by orders of magnitude. On the other side, `SQL Server` lacks running aggregates, and a `CLR` can help greatly. I need to see your requirements to give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 5):

Please see [Performance of CLR Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131075.aspx):

> This topic discusses some of the
>   design choices that enhance the
>   performance of Microsoft SQL Server
>   integration with the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework common language runtime
>   (CLR).

Answer (score 0):

The question of "Will writing a stored procedure in C# using the .net CLR as part of SQL Server 2008 cause my stored procedure to be less efficient than if it were written in T-SQL?" is really too broad to be given a meaningful answer. Efficiency varies greatly depending on not just what types of operations are you doing, but also *how* you go about those operations. You could have a CLR Stored Procedure that should out-perform an equivalent T-SQL Proc but actually performs worse due to poor coding, and vice versa.

Given the general nature of the question, I can say that "in general", things that can be done in T-SQL (without too much complexity) likely should be done in T-SQL. One possible exception might be for TVFs since the CLR API has a very interesting option to stream the results back (I wrote an article for SQL Server Central--free registration required--about [STVFs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/68850/)). But there is no way to know for certain without having both CLR and T-SQL versions of the code and testing both with Production-level data (even poorly written code will typically perform well enough with 10k rows or less).

So the *real* question here boils down to:

> I know C# better than I know T-SQL. What should I do?

And in this case it would be best to simply ask how to tackle this particular task in T-SQL.  It could very well be that there are non-complex solutions that you just don't happen to know about yet, but would be able to understand upon learning about the feature / technique / etc. And you can still code an equivalent solution in SQLCLR and compare the performance between them.  But if there is no satisfactory answer for handling it in T-SQL, then do it in SQLCLR.

That being said, I did do a study 3 years ago regarding SQLCLR vs T-SQL Performance and published the results on [Simple-Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-performance-testing/).